# Shortcut keys to delete all text to end of line (or all text after cursor)?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut

Edit: This question was marked as duplicate and closed, but I checked the suggested duplicates before asking mine and found they had different particulars, even if they were about the same topic.  If, however, I missed the exact duplicate, then I stand corrected.

When deleting all text before the cursor, you could use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, but what's the opposite equivalent when you want to delete all text after the cusor (or to the end of a line)?

Comment: The other question asks about "Is there any official macOS way to delete the line to the right of the cursor?" which looks like the same thing you are asking here. And the answer is the same there as well (Ctrl-K).

Comment: @nohillside Yep, I missed that one. I stand corrected. Although Ctrl-K actually deletes the entire paragraph, not just the line (just re-tested it now in both Apple Notes and TextEdit).

What I was looking for was a shorter alternative to Shift-Command-Right Arrow then Delete. But Ctrl-K isn't a total loss, still a useful combo.

Thanks still.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keyboard shortcut to delete after the cursor till end of line is <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: @Aiviar Paalberg Thank you so much, Aivar, this combo works perfectly. You'd think this info is easily found online but googling was no bueno. Thanks again, really appreciate it (life-changing, actually).